# How to upload zip on github with api using PHP & CURL

Tags: php, github, curl, automation, github-api

We are trying to automate some stuff

Basically now are stuck with GitHub part:

**What we want to do:**

- Upload/Push files using users API
- In Future we will update same repo (with update version)
- That's all

**What are we using**

We are looking to achieve this using PHP & CURL

Answer (score 1):

Since zip file are not a good fit for a GitHub *source* repository, you could:

- create a [release](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository)
- upload zip files associated with this release

This is done in command line using [`gh`, the GitHub LCI](https://cli.github.com/)

- [`gh release create v1.2.3`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create)
- [`gh release upload <tag> <files>...`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_upload)

You can [call that command from your PHP script](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).